# Why do some yeast flocculate on top an other at bottom?

Tags: yeast, fermentation

When fermenting beer normally after the fermentation has completed the yeast flocculate and drop to the bottom. However occationally they form a foamy layer on top of the beer.

The difference is maybe strain dependent. But exactly what is it that makes the yeast drop to the bottom or raise to the top of the beer?